# Azure AD Graph API: Bulk update of users

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

Does Azure AD Graph API support batch processing on users? As an example, if I want to update the location for several hundred users in my organization, is there any way I can do that? The only information I could find was what is described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-batch-processing

But as I understand, you can only batch operations on a single user entity in a given batch operation, and even that is limited to 5 operations per changeset. So my only option seems to be to sequentially invoke the API to update every single user in my list. I couldn't find any officially documented rate limiting that may be enforced by Microsoft. So I'm not sure if that approach would even work. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , Azure AD Graph API support batch processing on users . Please refer to [this code sample](https://github.com/CrazyTuna/azure-active-directory-batchprocessing) , check the `CreateUsersTest` function in that code sample . To make that sample work , you need to add `Read and write directory data` app permission for your client app :

[image]

Another way is to use powershell to add multiple users using a bulk import process:

1. first create a csv file with appropriate attributes like :

   [image]
2. Then you could install [Azure ActiveDirectory Powershell (MSOnline)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/?view=azureadps-1.0).
3. Connect the service :

   ```
   PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> connect-msolservice
   ```
4. Import users from csv file :

   ```
   $users = Import-Csv E:\a.csv
   ```
5. Create users with `New-MsolUser` command .

   ```
   $users | ForEach-Object {New-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $_.UserName -FirstName $_.FirstName -LastName $_.LastName –DisplayName $_.DisplayName -Title $_.JobTitle -Department $_.Department -Country $_.Country}
   ```

**Update :**

Please refer to document : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-batch-processing

> > The Graph API supports a subset of the functionality defined by the OData specification:
> >
> > A single batch can contain a maximum of five queries and/or change sets combined.
> >
> > A change set can contain a maximum of one source object modification and up to 20 add-link and delete-link operations combined. All operations in the change set must be on a single source entity.

In your scenario ,a single source entity means one user entity , you could create a user , modify that user in a change set , but can't create two users in one change set, since they're two entities .

It seems there is no such document lists  rate limiting for batch process , but i have tested create 2000+ users with above code and it works fine .

Comment: Thanks! The code sample and the powershell commands here do help.
However, I'm a little confused as to what a "single entity" means (as specified at the link I posted originally. I'm not sure if a changeset containing multiple user update requests (/users/<upn 1>, /users/<upn 2>....) is considered a valid changeset.
Also, this brings up my other question - Even with this batching, I can update only 5 users at a time.
If I'm updating 5000 users, that is still 1000 batch requests. Is there some rate limiting that might prevent me from doing that? If so, where do I get this information?

Comment: @sdworld , i have updated my answer to reply your question , please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That helps!